# Looking for examples of finite loops and monoids

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, examples-counterexamples, monoid, quasigroups

I am looking for examples of (small) finite loops and monoids that are not groups for demonstrating what happens if you omit some of the group axioms.

Does anyone know some ressources for this? I already used Wikipedia and Google but the problem I encountered was that I could not find any examples that were not groups.

Comment: Hi! Could you be more specific than _what happens if_? Which properties are you mainly interested in? I will update my answer with more resources consequently...

Comment: @MattAllegro Thank you for your answer so far! I am not looking for any special property, I am just looking for some examples, that are not groups but very 'close' to being groups. I'd just like to find 'small' examples, so the multiplication table does not get too big=)

Comment: Ok, seen. Keep an eye over this page in the next days, I'll update adding monoids also. Another resource I've cited here multiple times is: http://www.quasigroups.eu/contents/download/2011/19_1.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Monoids: have you checked the multiplicative structures over $\Bbb Z_n$ or over the matrices of finite given order with entries in a finite field?

Comment: @MattAllegro No, thank you for the hint! You mean equipping $\mathbb Z_n$ with the multiplication $\mod n$ where $n \neq p^m$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Start with this example if you're interested in the multiplication table.

Comment: @MattAllegro: I just tried it successfully: Write down the table of $R\setminus \{0\}$ and delete all rows/columns that contain a $0$. If there still are rows/columns with twice the same entry, we are finished! Works e.g. for $n=10$, where you end up removing the $5$-row/column.

Comment: Travis Willse asks [a related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216907/121988).

Comment: @PeterKagey Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several examples of finite loops (quasigroups with left and right identity) of *small* order with some additional properties can be found [here](http://ericmoorhouse.org/pub/bol/).

[Another source](http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0307/0307028.pdf) showing several examples of finite loops Cayley tables.

A [third example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619891/examples-of-loops-which-have-two-sided-inverses/768168#768168) of *very group-like* loop which is not a group, answer to a related Math.SE question.

Again, in the absence of associativity, inverses may be defined in a more general way: this is the case of [**inverse property loops**](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_property_loop). The smallest example of such loop which is not a group [has order $7$](http://www.quasigroups.eu/contents/download/2008/16_2.pdf). This latter is, to me, a brilliant example of what *may happen* if we *omit some of the group axioms* (associativity, in the case of loops).

Answer (score 1):

Another example. If $\mathbb O$ is an [algebra of octonions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) with a standard basis $e_0,\ldots,e_7$, then $L=\{\pm e_0,\pm e_1,\ldots,\pm e_7\}$ is a finite non-associative and non-abelian loop with elegant law of composition (Fano plane).